# C-like compound assignment operator in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In postgresql documentation, there is the entry regarding the "CREATE OPERATOR". I'm literally desperate for a compound assignment operator, C or C# like style, in my PL/PGSQL code. Ideally it would work like this

```
v_my_text += 'some more text to be added to existing value of v_my_text';
```

This would of course be the equivalent of

```
v_my_text := v_my_text || 'some more text...';
```

I was not able to find any example around the assignment operators. Is something like this possible?

Comment: `:=` is not a usual operator, it is [specific to the pl/pgsql assignment syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) and in fact just syntactic sugar for `SELECT … INTO …;`. You cannot redefine it, and you cannot define an operator that "uses" `:=` either. `CREATE OPERATOR` is for operators in (non-procedural) sql expressions.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I did not mention specifically so I just edited and added remark that I did ask within the context of plpgsql. I still hope this could be done.

Comment: I was talking about plpgsql already. No, it cannot be done.

Comment: Oh, ok... Thanks for looking into it. Then I can only hope that some next Postgresql version will natively provide such or similar operator. It would keep the code "more tidy" (IMHO).

Comment: Are you doing this a lot? You might want to ask a new question about how to simplify your code. Maybe using `string_agg` or similar.

Comment: Hello @Bergi. Again, thanks for the hint. Well, string_agg does a great job (I love that one)... but the context here is different, here comes more... I'm working on rather big project where we are moving away from Oracle and have to provide retro-compatible procedures in Postgresql (Azure). Meaning, the Signature (input and output parameters) must behave exactly like in old solution (the many other apps/DBs connecting, need not change too much).

Comment: Now, regardless how clever (or not that much) the old procedures were written, few of them are returning lot of "processing report" text in **single output parameter**.  I currently see no better way around it but to all over again go `v_output_report := v_output_report || 'CHECKPOINT: Validation x, y PASSED' || chr(13) || chr(10)`;

Comment: I was thinking of adding new text by passing e.g. `v_output_report` by reference to "utility" function/proc, but I stuck there also Passing that way would simplify anyway comlext procedure body. @Bergi: If you can hint me on passing variable by refernce, PLEASE!

Comment: Hm, I've heard about `inout` parameters, is that what you are looking for? I've never used them myself since I found them confusing

Answer (score 1):

According to feedbacks I was getting, creating `+=` operator is currently not possible. Yet, @Bergi gave me an idea with `inout` parameters which can simplify my code.

```
create or replace procedure add_line
(
    p_text_body inout text,
    p_new_text  in text
)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    p_text_body := p_text_body || p_next_text || chr(10) || chr(13);
end; $$
```

It would be used like `call add_line(v_output_report, 'New text line here...');`
Any better ideas are welcome. See comments on question for more context. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for procedure with INOUT parameter (or starting with v14 an OUT parameter). Instead just build an SQL function. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=527a876fb0871222e0691ced15d67805))

```
create or replace function add_line
                         ( p_text_body in text
                         , p_new_text  in text
                         )
    returns text 
   language sql
as $$
    select concat(p_text_body, E'\n', p_new_text);   
$$;
```

Notes:

- Use `E'\n'` ([4.1. Lexical Structure](https://%20https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html): 4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-Style Escapes) rather than `chr(10) || chr(13)`. It adjusts to the proper code for the operating system.
- The normal assignment operator in Postgres is just `=`. The += is strictly to maintain compatibility with Oracle plsql.
- The `concat` function is perhaps better than the concatenation operator (||) here as it handles NULLs. `concat('A', null)` or `concat(null, 'A' )` both return  'A' where as `'A' || null` or `null || 'A'` both return null.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @Belayer! One would probably never guess, but the "Postgresql Single Server" offering from Azure provides Version 11 only. I guess, I'm happy we're not stuck with version 8 or 9 :-)

Comment: "*The normal assignment operator is `=`, the `+=` is strictly to maintain compatibility*" - did you mean `:=`?

Comment: "*There is no need for procedure with INOUT parameter*" - but without that, you still need to name the variable twice in `v_my_text := add_line(v_my_text, 'some more text...');`, which is what the OP is trying to avoid

Comment: Yes, I meant `:=`.  But you do not need to name the variable twice; you use Select instead of assignment.